# Finding ascii value of list of a strings in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

I am having a problem for few hours. My problem as as follows:

i have a list of multiple string, for instance, l = ['jk','kl'].

I want to find out the ascii value of first list index that is 'jk'. I know ord() function takes only one character so i have loop over my list two times.
I wish to find the sum of ascii value of 'j' and 'k' and then saved into dictionary where key will be the index number of l and value would be the sum of ascii value of characters that corresponds to the index number of l. output for my given list of character(l) would be as following:

d = {0:213,1:215}

Here is my code:

```
l= ['jk','kl']
#for i in range(len(l)):
#print(sum([ord(it) for it in i]))
d = {}

for i in range(len(l)):
    for it in l[i]:
    d[i] = ord(it)
print(d)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You were quite close - you just have to initialize d's values to zero, and add to it in the inner loop.

```
l= ['jk','kl']
d = {}

for i in range(len(l)):
    d[i] = 0
    for it in l[i]:
        d[i] += ord(it)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you should just set the value to zero at the beginning and then add the number each time:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    d[i]=0
    for it in l[i]:
        d[i] += ord(it)
print(d)
```

Comment: oops, I was too slow :)